# Which carriers will my unlocked AT&T iPhone 4s work with?

Tags: iphone, unlock, cellular-carriers

I purchased a subsidized AT&T iPhone 4s in October 2011 (model MC922LL/A). I just unlocked the phone through AT&T's unlock website and received an email confirmation. I have backed up and restored the phone in iTunes and received the "Congratulations, your iPhone has been unlocked" message.

My question is, can I use my unlocked iPhone 4s with any of the following carriers:

- T-Mobile (GSM)
- Metro PCS (GSM)
- Verizon (CDMA)
- Straight Talk (CDMA)

Edit: I ended up trying Metro PCS and haven't had any problems. They're using T-Mobile's signal, which works with my 4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use it on any CDMA networks.  T-Mobile is no problem.  Metro PCS has a big "bring your own device" headline on its site so I'd guess it's OK as well.

Comment: Doesn't T-Mobile use the 1700 MHz band for their network? The [iPhone 4S specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP643) don't list it as supported.